# Extracting elements from a python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, jupyter-notebook

I want elements of odd index  from p in q_odd list and elements of even index  from p in q_even list.

```
p = [4, 8, 7,19,23,78,67,37,3783,4]

q_odd = []  
    
q_even = []
```

Result would be :

```
q_odd = [8,19,78,37,4]
    
q_even = [4,7,23,67,3783]
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I am trying for a for loop with if else statements , but unable to apply properly

Comment: This is giving us the odd elements value, we want elements of odd index @hiroprotagonist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(p)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        q_even.append(p[i])
    else:
        q_odd.append(p[i])
```

Comment: this is giving us the index values like not element values,  Result got q_even= [0,2,4,6,8]   result wanted - q_even= [4,7,23,67,3783]

Comment: this is giving us the index values like not element values,  Result got q_even= [0,2,4,6,8]   result wanted - q_even= [4,7,23,67,3783]  @divyessh

Comment: check it, now it will work

Comment: yes, it works now, Thanks buddy

Comment: @Andrew This is a very non-pythonic way of doing it. See hiro protagonist's answer for a better approach.

Comment: @Selcuk I feel that for beginners the simpler the code is the better they understand.

Comment: list slicing is a very basic technique. it is not about optimization. you will find yourself using that a lot if you continue with python. should you need `numpy` (or `pandas`) at some point you will not get around it. and i'd argue that it is easier to read for a python programmer... happy pythoning!

Comment: I agree @hiroprotagonist

Answer (score 5):

you can just use [list-slicing](https://www.learnbyexample.org/python-list-slicing/):

```
q_odd = p[1::2]
q_even = p[::2]
```

`p[start:stop:step]` creates a new list from the given list `p`. with `step=2` you take every other element, `start=0` (the default is `0` so there is not even a need to write that - you can just write `p[::2]`) will then give you the ones with even index; `start=1` the ones with odd index.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**
This should solve your problem statement:

```
p = [4, 8, 7,19,23,78,67,37,3783,4]
q_even, q_odd = [], []

# METHOD 1 : using continue with if condition for data processing
for idx, num in enumerate(p):
    if idx % 2 == 0:
        q_even.append(num)
        continue
    q_odd.append(num)

# METHOD 2 : Using if-else statement for data processing
for idx, num in enumerate(p):
    if idx % 2 == 0:
        q_even.append(num)
    else:
        q_odd.append(num)

# Method 3: using list-slicing : as explained by '@hiro protagonist'
q_odd = p[1::2]
q_even = p[::2]

print(q_odd)
print(q_even)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[8, 19, 78, 37, 4]
[4, 7, 23, 67, 3783]
```

**NOTE: USE ONLY ONE METHOD AT A TIME**

Comment: Or within `if .. else` block.

Comment: updated code with if-else statement. Have a look. it will work perfectly well.

Answer (score -1):

```
p = [4, 8, 7,19,23,78,67,37,3783,4]
q_even = [p[i] for i in range(len(p)) if i%2 == 0]  
print(q_even)
q_odd = [p[i] for i in range(len(p)) if i%2 != 0]
print(q_odd)
# Have used list comprehension.
```